# C++ QT vs C# .NET for Windows Development

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, qt

I'm currently having some analysis paralysis in deciding which is better for me between C++ using the Qt framework, or C# using the .NET framework for developing a small to medium sided project I currently designing.

I have a little experience in both languages, slightly more in C++ however would probably still be considered a novice.

All the information I have read has been relativity outdated (being at least a couple of years old) and was wondering if there have been any updates that would swing the advantage one way or another, or if it really is just a matter of preference.

QT seems to support my particular requirements needs slightly better however the additional difficulty of working in C++ may offset taking me back to square 1.

My requirements are fairly simple, I will need rich text support, database connections, the ability to export to various file types and have a fairly dynamic GUI.

Anyone have any personally experiences or recommendations they wish to share?

Comment: If your app is for Windows only: C#/.NET. If your app is cross-platform: C++/Qt.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recommend to use Qt because:

- It's cross-platform and covers wide range of operating systems (including mobile)
- Writing in C++ gives you the opportunity to use libraries
  like the STL, Boost, etc;
- Using C++ gives you the benefit of running your app at high speed
- It is opensource and has a fast speed in getting better
- It has the a nice GUI designer and a very capable IDE (Qt Creator)
- The API design is excellent and easy to use
- It has a great documentation which is easy to read
- It has the Qt translation system which enables you to have a multilingual app
- The GUI layout system where the widgets resize themselves according to a layout makes everything much easier
- The QML gives you the power to create fantastic GUI with great graphics and animations
- It has great support for networking and connectivity(socket, SSL, www, IPC, ...)
- It has QTestLib for testing the code
- It has many language binding if you don't want to use C++

Comment: I have used both for creating GUI and .Net is way easier, more concise and better documented (msdn rocks). It is cross-platform too if you use Xamarin C#. Also C# and .Net is open source now.

Comment: @kami C++ and C# are both heavily documented programming languages, also C++ is not harder or easier than C#, that's completely based on the person programming with that languages.  Also you don't compare languages by saying one is 'easier' than the other, you list advantages such as longevity, compatibility, maintainability, etc.  Also just because a language/platform is open source doesn't necessarily mean anything for a programmer.

Comment: @thedanny09 I mentioned C# is open source because in the above post, the author recommended Qt because it is open source. Moreover, being an open-source can be advantage or disadvantage and it is a valid point in deciding which language to use and it is important for some companies (some of them have even a policy on that). Also you mentioned "...that's completely based on the person...". I strongly disagree on that. counter-sample: Machine code is obviously harder than the Sketch for almost all of the people.

Comment: I agree with Kami.   C# is easier to use for reasons already stated and the IL is much easier to use and debug with. PERIOD!!!.  Not only that, but there is Reflection which allows you to do dynamic programming.  There is no way I would ever go back to C++ if I had the choice.   Java doesn't even compare to C#.   Plus, you don't have all the boilerplate crap.   I do like some of the c++ constructs, multi-inheritance, but much more dangerous and allows for bad arch/anti-patterns. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

Answer (score 6):

1. You can learn Qt easily if you know C++
2. All requirements you have given are completely feasible and easy to do in Qt
3. It doesn't require any VM for deployment but .NET needs that.
4. Your application will be cross platform
5. Creating custom UI is very much possible in Qt. You can create almost any kind of UI in Qt.

Comment: .NET does not require a VM (virtual machine?)

Comment: QT needs library to run.QT library is big(more than 500 Mb)

Comment: @DaveInCaz .NET *is* a VM (virtual machine), just like Java.

Comment: @EsmailJamshidiasl Only for development, not deployment!